# Reading input from a file and distinguishing between square brace and normal brace - [a, b) in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a file which has the below content 
input

```
1,
3,
(1, 60),
[52, 67],  
(-1, 34]
```

the first line represents the test case, the second line represents the number of inputs and the subsequent lines each represent the range of input values for each test case. I know how to read a file and parse it, how do I distinguish between inclusive '[' bracket and exclusive '(' bracket, based on these I have to include or exclude the corresponding end values in the input. please help I am stuck here.

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList< >();
    try(BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Name))){
    String line;
    while((line = Br.readLine()) != null){
        list.add(line);
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int var = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
    int   n = Integer.parseInt(list.get(1));
    ArrayList<String> start = new ArrayList< >();
    ArrayList<String> end = new ArrayList< >();
    for(int i = 2; i < n+2; i++){
        start.add(list.get(i));
        end.add(list.get(i));

    }
```

Comment: You can [edit] your own questions to fix mistakes instead of commenting on them - it would make the question clearer

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you share some code? It would give more context to the question and help us help you.